# How to join variable to specific row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, join

I am trying to join variables by row in SQL server. However, I'm not sure how to selectively map them. I have the following:

```
declare @p1 nvarchar(max) = '[{i:1, n:"one"}]'
declare @p2 nvarchar(max) = '[{i:2, n:"two"}]'
declare @p3 nvarchar(max) = '[{i:3, n:"three"}]'

select 
    [noRow] = row_number() over(order by [number] asc), 
    [table],
    [data1] = sd.one,
    [data2] = sd.two
from someDb sd
inner join @p1 on [noRow] = 1
inner join @p2 on [noRow] = 2
inner join @p2 on [noRow] = 3 
-- etc.
```

**Desired Output**

```
| noRow | data1 | data2 | table | 
|-------+-------+-------+-------|
| 1     | a     | b     | @p1   |
| 2     | c     | d     | @p2   |
| 3     | e     | f     | @p3   |
```

How can I join these variables to specific rows in SQL Server?

Comment: What version of SQL Server is the DB?  That matters because SQL 2016 has built in JSON parsing.  Best way would be to parse out your JSON to temp tables and then do the joins on your temp tables.  Or look into JSON parsing and you can do it directly if the sizes are not too complex.

Comment: 2016. I'm looking to have the json be stored in single table cells by row.

Comment: Then I would suggest parsing each JSON out FIRST, then joining to the fields in the DB you need to do your join on.

Comment: The json is parsed, updates are made, then it needs to go back into string form as a variable.

Comment: Sample data plus expected results would help clarify.

Comment: @DaleK Updated variables with data.

Comment: Its still far from clear what your desired output is... nor how the tables comes into play.

Comment: @DaleK The select is a bit garbled, but hopefully the desired output table makes it clear.

Comment: `@p1` in the expected output is the actual JSON or is it just the literal text `@p1`? And you want to join the rows by `p1.id=norow`?

Comment: @Charlieface It's just text. I'd like to join var 1 to row 1, var2 to row 2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from your comments that you want to display the actual variable name in the `table` column. I don't quite understand why you would want that, but here are your options:

```sql
select
    sd.noRow,
    sd.data1,
    sd.data2,
    v.[table]
from (
    select 
        noRow = row_number() over(order by number asc), 
        data1 = sd.one,
        data2 = sd.two
    from someDb
) sd
inner join (values
    ('@p1',@p1),
    ('@p2',@p2),
    ('@p3',@p3)
) v([table],json) on JSON_VALUE(v.json, '$[0].i') = sd.norow
```

If you wanted the full JSON then you can change `v.[table]` in the select list to `v.json`

If you wanted the `n` value out of the JSON, then you need this:

```sql
    [table] = JSON_VALUE(v.json, '$[0].n')
```

If you have a lot of these parameters you may want to consider a Table-Valued Parameter.